# Differentiating $\frac{dy}{dx}=3x+2y+xy$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What would $y''$ be of $\frac{dy}{dx}=3x+2y+xy$? In other words, what is the result ($y''$) if I differentiate $y'=3x+2y+xy$?

Can I do the following:

Set $$f(x,y) = 3x+2y+xy$$
then
$$f'(x,y) = \frac{df}{dx} + \frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$ f'(x,y) = (3 + y)+(2+x)(y')$$
$$ f'(x,y) = 3 + y + 2y'+ xy'$$
?

Comment: $f'$ doesn't make much sense if $f$ takes two variables. Also, is it $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ you want?

Comment: @Arthur - yes, I want $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression for $y''$ is correct, now you just need to substitute $y'$ from the equation given to you.

Also, your notation is incorrect. It should be$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Comment: If I don't substitute and differentiate one step further would it be $$y'''=2y'+2y'y'' + xy'y''$$? Not very confident with these...

Comment: @Tightrope Almost. $\frac d{dx}(2y')=2y''$. You made a similar error in differentiating $xy'$. Do you see it now?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It should be $y'''=2y'+2y''+xy''$.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$\frac {dy}{dx} = 3x + 2y + xy$

Differentiate both sides using the rules of implicit differentiation:

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} (3x + 2y + xy)\\
\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx} 3x + \frac{d}{dx}2y + \frac{d}{dx}xy\\
\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} = 3 + 2\frac {dy}{dx} + y + x\frac{dy}{dx}\\
$

We can substitute $\frac {dy}{dx} = 3x + 2y + xy$ from the begining

$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} = 3 + y + (2+x)(3x + 2y + xy)$

And simplify.

Comment: What "implicit differentiation"? It looks quite explicit to me. We have a function $y(x)$ (which may have been implicit at some point, but it isn't any more), and we know it fulfills a certain differential equation. Differentiating that equation again isn't implicit.

Comment: @Arthur Based on the tone of the question, I am assuming that the OP is not taking multivariable calculus, and at this point, the only time he has seen x's and y's all together on the same side of the equation has been in learning implicit differentiation.  Applying those techniques, as above, certainly works even if what we have here is something technically different.